# Sort command in Perl - Can someone explain what is happening in this script?

Tags: perl, sorting

new coder here working in Perl.  Can someone explain to me what the following portion of the below code is doing?  I know that it is performing an alphabetical sort of the elements in array @animals and I think it is then assigning the sorted index values to @idx.  I have no idea what the last portion "0 .. $#animals;" is doing.  It appears that '..' is the range operator in Perl.

```
my @idx = sort { 
$animals[$a] cmp $animals[$b] 
} 0 .. $#animals;
```

Here is the full code:

```
@animals = (dog,cat,iguana,parakeet,monkey, giraffe);
@diets = (beef,chicken,chickpeas,seeds,bananna,tree);
@age = (7,3,5,2,20,18);

my @idx = sort { 
$animals[$a] cmp $animals[$b] 
} 0 .. $#animals;

@animals = @animals[@idx];
@diets = @diets[@idx];
@age = @age[@idx];

print "@animals\n";
print "@diets\n";
print "@age\n";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$#animals` is the index of the last entry in `@animals`; in your example, that'd be `5`.

The range operator takes that `0 .. 5` and expands it to `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

That list of integers gets passed to `sort`, which treats them as indexes into `@animals` and sorts them based on the value in that array.

*Incidentally, parallel arrays make a great candidate for some other structure, like an array of hash references.*